# Coldfusion - Setting/Using URL Parameters

Tags: url, coldfusion, url-parameters

In ColdFusion, I understand how to work with URLs using the query string functions: i.e., the second parameter in:

```
test.cfm?par1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3
```

can be accessed by:

```
 <cfset Param2 = ListGetAt(CGI.QUERY_STRING,2,"&")>
```

However, I was tasked with making dynamic URLs with the parameters separated simply by slashes, i.e.:

```
test.cfm/val1/val2/val3
```

How can I construct a URL this way, and then utilize those parameters in the webpage it links to?

Edit: I understand it would be quite easy to construct a string that is "test.cfm/#val1#/#val2#/#val#" and use it as my URL; I was wondering if there was a cleaner, built-in way for CF to help me do it. I am still lost on how to access those in the page.

Comment: The info is stored in cgi.PATH_INFO when you do your links like that.  You can use your method for getting access: ListGetAt(CGI.PATH_INFO,2,"/")>

Comment: Download a copy of the FW/1 application framework and have a look at the source code. It has a very good SES URL parser included in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Param2 = listChangeDelims(CGI.QUERY_STRING,"/","&");
```

That will turn "foo=bar&sna=fu" into "foo=bar/sna=fu".

Or `listChangeDelims(CGI.QUERY_STRING,"/","&=");`
will change it to "foo/bar/sna/fu"